# Where does hydrogen evolution occur when aluminium amalgam is placed in water - aluminium or mercury?

Tags: physical-chemistry, electrochemistry

Let's say a drop mercury is placed on clean aluminium sheet; mercury amalgam is formed. The solubility of aluminium in mercury and vise versa at room temperature is fairly low. If the entire sheet is now placed under water, hydrogen evolution is observed. Where is this hydrogen evolution from - the aluminium rich surface on the edges or the mercury rich surface on the drop?

(For reference, please look up videos of aluminium amalgam online, say on YouTube.)

Comment: And what do you think? This sounds very much an educational question, which means you should do your homework for it!

Comment: It is an interesting question, an aluminium or zinc amalgam in contact with water is a very complex and interesting system